# Convert html layout table to div tag and CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to convert the table below into a series of `DIV` tags, styled with CSS. I have used `text-align`, and am familiar with `display: block;` and `margin: auto` type tricks, but nothing gives me the same result as this simple table layout:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div>some objects</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue with using the other approaches I'm familiar with is that they rely on me knowing the width of the objects I'm trying to align - which I don't. I want to be able to center arbitrarily wide objects, such as buttons and images.

Comment: what doesn't work? do you want the "some objects" should be in center of the parent container and thats all?

Comment: yes, i want to center the objects in a parent container without knowledge about the width of the objects.

Comment: might consider posting what your tried, because you gave the answer your self. Using margin:auto and text-align:center would work

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;` works perfectly anyway. If you are suffering from this, try to use `text-align: center;`

```
div{margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;} /* Replace div to your selector. */
```

After you could use `text-align: left;` if you like to others.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a div like this...

HTML

```
<div class="example">
    Some objects!
</div>
```

CSS

```
.example {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I am slightly guessing that you are just using the table in order to make the `div` tag appear in the middle of the screen - the margin style does this.

To center child elements, which I guess are also `div` elements, you need to do two things.

```
.example {
    text-align: center;
}

.example .button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I can be more specific if you can show me your markup - maybe on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I tried all of this things here, but nothing works fine for me. Here is a screeny of my problem: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/clipboard02nw.jpg/). I want to center the 6 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there can be achieved with exactly this:

```
<div>some objects</div>
```

css:

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

No more fuzz needed. `text-align` basically centers the content, so you can place other elements into that div which get perfectly centered automatically.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr5F2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want your inner div to be in center of the outer container, you can simply do this (without using table):

```
<div class="parent">
   <div>some objects</div>
</div>
```

Where `.parent` is:

```
.parent
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HndUa/).

You just have to use `text-align:center` CSS to center align your inner content.

Note that, parent container must have enough width to show visible spaces at the left and right ends.

Comment: I tried all of this things here, but nothing works fine for me. Here is a screeny of my problem: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/clipboard02nw.jpg/). I want to center the 6 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:table;`

http://jsfiddle.net/3Z4E8/

```
<div class"table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="text-align:center">
      <div>some objects</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

See the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Comment: you really don't need to nest 4 divs for that 1 div

Comment: and still it's not centered;)

Comment: I'd do centring with `margin`. Yeah this is more useful for when you're planning to use the layout of tables in more than one block.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code here with CSS and `div`s:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #td{
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div>some objects</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="table">
            <div id="td">
                Some objects
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please run the above code. Both are displaying in the same manner. If the above is not what you want, then please can you show what you tried?

Comment: I tried all of this things here, but nothing works fine for me. Here is a screeny of my problem: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/clipboard02nw.jpg/). I want to center the 6 buttons.

Comment: <div id="table">
    <div id="td">
    some objects
    </div>
   <div id="td">
    some more objects
    </div>
</div>
 like this place your buttons and try

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;` to center the objects in a parent container without knowledge about the width of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tabletodivconverter.com](http://www.tabletodivconverter.com) to convert html layout table to div tag and CSS. Did I mention that it's free?